# Java Spring MongoDB ORM not deleting file with deleteById(id)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to delete an entry in the database

The entry looks like this in the MongoDB:

> _id
> "11c4ee15-0048-4cc6-8a62-38e40389f2a8"
> title
> "DELETE ME"
> content
> "This is Lesson number 1"

I am using this repository:

```
public interface LessonRepository extends MongoRepository<Lesson, UUID> {
}
```

Why does this call fail without finding the id:

```
    public void deleteLesson(UUID id) {
        lessonRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

The model looks like this:

```
@Data
public class Lesson {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

My guess it that the id is not defined correctly. But defining it as a UUID gives me a binary object? Why doesn't it look like an ObjectId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried modifying your repository to:

```
public interface LessonRepository extends MongoRepository<Lesson, String> {
}
```